# discord.py temporary voices

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

I am making my bot for discord, I want to do this, when a user clicks on a certain voice channel, a new voice channel is created for him, which is deleted upon exit. Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'xxxx'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel != None:
        if after.channel.id == 700246237244555338:
            for guild in bot.guilds:
                maincategory = discord.utils.get(
                    guild.categories, id=700246237244555336)
                channel2 = guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'канал {member.display_name}', category=maincategory)
                await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, manage_channels=True)
                await member.move_to(channel2)

                def check(x, y, z):
                    return len(channel2.members) == 0
                await bot.wait_for('voice_state_update', check=check)
                await channel2.delete()


# RUN
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

But i have error...

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "jett.py", line 190, in on_voice_state_update
    await member.move_to(channel2)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 626, in move_to
    await self.edit(voice_channel=channel, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 592, in edit
    payload['channel_id'] = vc and vc.id
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'id'
C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py:340: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Guild.create_voice_channel' was never awaited
  pass
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

**Can you help me with this problem or just send me working code for temporary voices**

Comment: I believe this may be caused by intents, the new feature in discord.py 1.5.0. You need to subscribe to the intent that checks for members. See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#i-don-t-like-this-can-i-go-back)

Comment: ``But I have error`` - it would help if you'd put the error traceback in here as well

Comment: Already put error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback` usually means that you forgot to add an await keyword to an async function. The async function in question is likely `create_voice_channel`, as the documentation says it is an [async function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel).

To fix this, you'll want to add the await keyword before the function call, similar to this:

```
channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'канал {member.display_name}', category=maincategory)
```

Comment: tnx broooo))))))